# UIButton EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, exc-bad-access

I have an UI button and it works correctly when I pressed.
But if I press the button three times, I get an EXc_BAD_ACCESS error.
I thought I release something in somewhere but I couldn't find the solution.
Could you please help me?
Kind regards.

This is the function when I pressed the button. And in dealloc I release them. When I am tracking, it doesn't give the error in function. I got it after function, but I dont know where the code goes after this function.

```
- (IBAction) doSomething: (id)sender
{
    [self.answerDict replaceObjectAtIndex:currentPageNumber withObject:@"1"];
    [self.b setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.c setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.d setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.e setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];        

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.jpg"];
    [self.a setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [img release];
}
```

Comment: Can you enabled NSZombieEnabled for your executable and see what the console shows then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.jpg"];
[self.a setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[img release];
```

`[img release];` is the problem. You are releasing an object which you dont own. `img` in this case is auto-released.

Remove `[img release];` and see if the crash occurs

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to comment the code line by line and in that way you will understand what is the purpose of BAD_ACCESS error. At firs close whole code in the doSomething: may be the main reason is in your button ...